# Wifi connection keeps switching between different access points

Tags: networking, wireless

My WiFi connection keeps switching between different access points,

I have already set my regulatory domain to be explicit and I have set IPv6 to Ignore in the Network Manager

I have also bound my access point in the Network Manager icon, by filling in in the MAC address for my access point.

Still it keeps switching different access points!

You can find my wireless script output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12749837/)

Comment: actually, I guess the repeater channels are supposed to stay on the same channel which is odd because I've seen roaming channels broadcast on varying channels such as the ones at the university or even the "cable wifi" public channels.

Comment: You say you have set the BSSID in network-manager. What is the output of the following command: `ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Comment: this is the output;131   erez                       sdf       telenet-33857
+6    Familie Bzl                sdfq      telenet-377BC
651   HTC Portable Hotspot C308  sdqf      telenet-apn-A9D84
ds    IG-Intern                  sfd       TELENETHOMESPOT
ds 1  J_G                        SNOW5_34  TELENETHOTSPOT
dv    Mobistar-3294              sqdf      TTK-E2

Comment: this is a better way to look at it;  http://paste.ubuntu.com/12752627/

Comment: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with my Eero mesh network in my home. On windows everything is fine, on Ubuntu every 5 seconds it will jump to a different AP. I think it thinks the signal strength is low, and that's why it switches, but it is very frustrating

Answer (score 2):

**What you're describing is *behaviour by design!***

I suppose `TELENETHOMESPOT` is a network of hot spots set up by an ISP using residential routers so that when you're not at home, but near another customer of that same ISP, you can pick up their network.

Well now, that is the same thing large companies do with multiple antennas all broadcasting the same SSID, but on different channels depending on where in the building you are...

However, in a large company, they're all on the same network, and that's where your issue comes in: if the ISP didn't make this one big roaming network (which wouldn't surprise me as it's a `HOMESPOT` and not a `HOTSPOT`) you're actually switching between vastly different networks with each their own DHCP server instead of one vast network with only one DHCP server *which is really annoying!*

Therefore the only solution for such a residential `HOMESPOT` network is to *go and sit as close to one of the routers as possible!*  Alternatively, call the ISP and ask them if they have a *real* `HOTSPOT` network available and having experience with quite a few ISPs all over EMEA, that'll be an extra *payable* service...

Comment: And poor implementation on the part of the ISP because they are all on the same channel.

Comment: :D  *Extremely* probable!  @mchid

Answer (score 1):

First of all, delete all the networks from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections that you don't want to connect to. In fact, if you don't mind setting up your existing connection again, you can go ahead and delete everything in this directory. As it is now, network-manager remembers all the networks you have connected to in the past and so it is trying to connect to familiar networks automatically.

The following commands will move these to a backup directory in your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/wifibackup
sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* ~/wifibackup
```

Now, restart network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You will need to reestablish your connection to the network. After doing so, set the BSSID in network-manager and remember to restart network-manager to apply the settings after you do.

---

Also, I found some posts and have seen a lot of people have wireless issues because of a conflicting module. So, if the above isn't enough try running the following commands to resolve the issue:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d/.blacklistbackup
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: This din't work, it keeps switching between the different access points named "TELENETHOMESPOT"

Comment: Then set the **BSSID** to a static value and remember you must reconnect to the network after doing so to apply the changes or it won't work.

Comment: @jozef Also, you can try setting your IP to a static value. After obtaining an IP through DHCP, set that IP to a static value, along with netmask and gateway. I think DNS usually works when set to the same as gateway but if not you can use 8.8.4.4 or opendns or whatever. Again, after making these changes, reconnect to the network by clicking on it to refresh the new settings. Hopefully, even if you do roam, you won't have to go through the hassle of obtaining a new IP each time.

Comment: @jozef click on **connection information** to obtain the proper addresses.

Comment: howdou you do this specificly? changing your ip adress etc? is it in IP4 or IP6 settings?

Comment: @jozef IPV4 Click on **connection information** and you should get a list of your **IP Address**, **Subnet Mask**, **Default Route** and **Primary DNS**. Go to network-manager, click edit connections, click on the network and click edit.

Comment: @jozef Go to IPV4 and select manual from the drop down menu and then click add. First, type the **IP address** number then press TAB, type the **subnet mask** number and the press TAB, type the **default route** number and then click in the box for DNS server and type the primary DNS number and then click save. If you mess up, you will have to start over. Then, click on the network to reconnect to the network to apply the changes.